# Which Data Structure provides Replace Operation when appending Duplicate?

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap

is there a Data-Structure which eliminates duplicates with low complexity? When appending a new Value, it should be not added when there is already the same value.

Can this be achieved with Heaps?

Thanks!

Comment: A modified hash table would work for this.

Answer (score 2):

std::set does so. In fact, if you want this not to happen, you need to switch to multisets.

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/) of set

> Because elements in a set are unique, the insertion operation checks
>   whether each inserted element is equivalent to an element already in
>   the container, and if so, the element is not inserted, returning an
>   iterator to this existing element (if the function returns a value).

Comment: And the complexity is low - std:set takes time proportional to log(number of elements). Using an unordered_set would give you constant time on average.

Answer (score 1):

No, I do not think that heaps help in this problem.

Probably the fastest way is to use hash tables. They are available in C++11 or in Boost as unordered_set (unordered_multiset allows duplicates though).

The second approach could be to use binary search tree, like C++98 standard std::set (again, multiset allows duplicates), which is usually implemented by a red-black tree.

A third, but limited option would be to sort the elements first, and then remove duplicates, which are now consecutive. This is feasible only if you first add all elements, and all the lookups come after that. Otherwise you are restricted to the first two options. C++ provides you std::sort and std::unique to use this approach.

Regarding performace:

- Hash tables: every access O(1), assuming that you have a good hash function.
- Balanced binary search trees: every access O(log n) in worst case.
- Sort + remove duplicates: for all n elements O(n * log n), but probably with a lower constant factor than with binary trees.